# Setting IP address in Node-Red, to an UDP-out node

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

My node-red flow includes an udp-out node with my computer's ip address. But this changes from time to time, so then I manually need to change it. The tooltip for the UDP-out node says to leave the address blank if you want to use msg.ip to set.

How do I use msg.ip? I haven't find a solution to this. It keeps reporting udp address not set.

Answer (score 0):

You leave it blank in the config dialog for the node, then on EVERY message you want to send out via the node you need to set `msg.ip` to the ip address you want to send the message to.

The following flow demonstrates:

```
[{"id":"238e2695.98a252","type":"udp out","z":"59370ac1.51144c","name":"","addr":"","iface":"","port":"","ipv":"udp4","outport":"","base64":false,"multicast":"false","x":547.5,"y":181,"wires":[]},{"id":"2a002216.f8cb3e","type":"inject","z":"59370ac1.51144c","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":141.5,"y":180,"wires":[["6d51ce96.66603"]]},{"id":"6d51ce96.66603","type":"change","z":"59370ac1.51144c","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"ip","pt":"msg","to":"ip","tot":"flow"},{"t":"set","p":"port","pt":"msg","to":"port","tot":"flow"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":353.5,"y":180,"wires":[["238e2695.98a252"]]}]
```

It assumes you set the `flow.ip` and `flow.port` from some other source in the flow.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but can you explain more : set msg.ip to the ip address you want to send message to? How you set msg.ip

Comment: Use a function node or a change node to attach a property to the `msg` called `ip` with the ip address you want before it flows into the UDP node

Comment: So, if i understood this right....I recivce an string with the ip address typed in from my C# program, to udp in node, port 10000. Then into an change node, changing msg.payload to msg.ip. Then into udp out, with blank address field. Still posting udp address not set.

Comment: No, the `msg.payload` needs to be what data you want to send in the UDP packet. You need both `msg.paylaod` and `msg.ip`  (and `msg.port` unless you put that in the config dialog) in order to send a message

Comment: Could you show me an example of this in a function or change node? msg.port is in the config.